# Mediation: Significant indirect effect, but total effect nonsignificant, no inconsistent mediation

Tags: bootstrap, mediation, lavaan

I conducted a mediation analysis via lavaan. For estimating all effects, I used 10,000 bootstraps. [image]

I have problems interpeting my results.

Path a is negative and significant.
Path b is positive and significant.
Path c is negative, but not significant.

The indirect effect aXb is small, negative, but significant.
However, the total effect aXb+c is not significant, although its absolute value is greater than the indirect effect (since aXb and c are both negative).
So I don't have the case of an inconsistent mediation, since the mediator doesn't suppress the effect of X on Y.

Is it really possible that the indirect effect can be significant in bootstraps, while the total effect is not although it is greater than the indirect effect? Can I still interpret a mediation? If c was positive, then the total effect would be smaller than the indirect effect and then it would make sense that the indirect effect is significant while the total effect is not.